# Protractor - How to verify if the toggle button is selected/Enabled or not selected?

Tags: angularjs, jquery-mobile, jasmine, protractor, appium

I am using protractor to Automate the mobile app. I need to verify if the toggle button(Toggle button Image attached) is checked or not, or enabled or disabled.
If not selected, select and do some operations, but everytime it says, selected even if not selected and disabled.[image: Toogle button image attached]

Here is my Code attached:::::::::::

```
var checkNoti = AppNoti.isSelected();


    if (checkNoti)
    {
        checkNoti.then( function() {
            console.log('The App notification is enabled Already!!');
        });

    }
    else {

        AppNoti.click().then( function() {
            console.log('The App notification is Enabled');
                        });
            };
```

Kindly advise...All the time, it says, toggle checkbox button is enabled, even if its disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkNoti` value in the `if (checkNoti)` check would always evaluate as true since it is not a boolean value - it is a promise. You need to **resolve** it:

```
AppNoti.isSelected().then(function (selected) {
    if (!selected) {
        AppNoti.click().then(function() {
            console.log('The App notification is Enabled');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello Alecxe,Thanks for the update.. I tried this, but didnt worked. Getting an unknown server side error. and the toggle button is not checked, if its unchecked. Please find below the error log from protractor.........................     UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the co
mmand.
   Stacktrace:
     UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
    at new bot.Error -webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113:18)

Comment: @Bhawani could you at least try this: put `console.log(selected);` on the second line, before the `if` statement? Thanks.

Comment: Hello Alecxe, Thanks a lot for the efforts. Its working now... console.log(selected) display false if not selected....

Answer (score 0):

You can click on it if it is enabled

```
AppNoti.click().then(function()
{

   console.log('The App notification is Enabled');

}, function(err){

   console.log('The App notification is Disabled');
});
```